# Does Google Indexes content generated by JavaScript "On Scroll Load More"?

Tags: seo, google, googlebot

I'm implementing a "on scroll load more" page on my website and I'm wondering if google, now that crawls and indexes JavaScript, will see my content, does it?

Comment: Are you expecting a scroll event from googlebot?? I wouldn't.

Comment: @closetnoc  I'm actually not expecting anything, I'm simply asking. A couple of years ago google wouldn't index JS and now it does, so I was wondering about this. Tks.

Comment: Google as been doing th JS thing for quite a few years now, however, in the last 3-4 years they have gotten much better. Still, I would not expect an event from them except for things such as a drop-down box and such. Back in the day when Google started doing the JS thing, it was to get to the pages hidden behind AJAX and other stuff. Scroll is different especially with the infinite scroll sites that people are creating. So I would not bet on a scroll event. Of course, you can always try an experiment! ;-) Cheers!!

Comment: might be problem if your page really is "infinite scroll". Users my get bored scrolling after a time but a bot would keep on going forever or until a timeout was reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article suggests that Google will cache content loaded by an onscroll event: http://dinbror.dk/blog/lazy-load-images-seo-problem/

Admittedly that is for images, but I can't see why it wouldn't work for other content.

I would test though.